# Video react - How to Subcribe to state change

Tags: reactjs, html5-video, video-reactjs

I tried subscribeToStateChange but keep getting `TypeError: playerRef.subscribeToStateChange is not a function`
not sure what im doing wrong since I am using functional components.

here is the useEffect hook - trying to subscribe and set state at the same time

```
       React.useEffect(() => {
            playerRef.subscribeToStateChange(setstate(player?.getState()))
        });
```

Does anyone know how to solve  this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-----------SOLUTION --------------------

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (player) {
        player.subscribeToStateChange(handleBind)
    }
});

function handleBind(state) {
    setstate(state);
}
```